# burglr::burgle is not containing any contents in burgled.R

Tags: r, devtools

I wanted to copy a function from the `stringr` package. I did the following::

```
library(devtools)
create_package("D:/path/to/dda")
use_package("stringr")
use_package("burglr")
burglr::burgle(stringr::fixed)
```

I got this message:

> Copying stringr:::fixed and its dependencies
>
> stringr  is licensed:  GPL-2 | file LICENSE   and is by:   Hadley
> Wickham [aut, cre, cph],   RStudio [cph, fnd]  Remember to comply with
> the terms of the license of the code you are using.
>
> ```
>       See https://r-pkgs.org/license.html for more info.
> ```

Also, I was able to find that a new file in /.R directory, named burgled.R was created. but it has only this content :

```
# generated by {burglr}
```

No code copied from stringr is inside this file except that one line "# generated by {burglr}"

I got the `burglr` package [here](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/burglr).

Comment: If `burglr::burgle()` doesn't work try burgling `burglr::burgle()` and then running `burgle()` directly from `burgled.R`.

Comment: its not working !

Comment: Sorry I was joking - I think probably you should post this as a github issue if you haven't already.